# How to call ajax through Bootstrap button in yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to use Ajax through bootstrap button in Yii, and want to pass textfield values though that Ajax call.

here's the button code, where should i put the Ajax code for this button.

```
   <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'button', 'label'=>'ADD')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'button', 'label'=>'ADD',

     'ajaxOptions' => array(
                    'type' => 'Post',
                    'url' => $this->createURL('url'),
                    'data' => Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName."=".Yii::app()->request->getCsrfToken()."&action=cancel",
                    'success'=>"js:function(vals){


                    }",
                    )
    )); ?>
```

another eg:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                 'buttonType' => 'ajaxButton',
                 'label' => 'Label Here',
                 'type' => 'danger',
                 'icon' => 'play white',
                 ...
                 'ajaxOptions' => array(
                     'success' => '...',
                     'error' => '...',
                     'beforeSend' => '...',
                 )
             ));
```

Comment: ok. but what does this line mean, 'data' => Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName."=".Yii::app()->request->getCsrfToken()."&action=cancel",

Comment: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). you can omit that. To prevent CSRF attacks, it is important to abide to the rule that GET requests should only be allowed to retrieve data rather than modify any data on the server. And for POST requests, they should include some random value which can be recognized by the server to ensure the form is submitted from and the result is sent back to the same origin.

Comment: to know more about using csrf token in yii check this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security#cross-site-request-forgery-prevention

Comment: I want to send textfield's data through ajax, how can I do so?

Comment: add that in the data param like 'data'=>'user=name&age=10' etc

Comment: I tried it using CHtml::Ajaxbutton, its working fine, but when I try it as above, nothing happens...
here's code,
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'button', 'label'=>'ADD', 'ajaxOptions' => array(
                        'type' =>'POST',
                        'url' =>    Yii::app()->createUrl('site/getlist'),
                        'success' => 'function(result) {
                             alert(\'working\');
                        }',
                        'dataType' => 'html'
))); ?>

Comment: did you check the console. check if the call is happening

Comment: change the button Type to ajaxButton like this.  array('buttonType'=>'ajaxButton',....)